# Does the summoned monsters alignment affect the school description?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, alignment, summoning

When you cast the spell summon monster, does the summoned creatures alignment affect the spell description for the school?

So would a good cleric be allowed to summon a Lemure from SM2 which is a lawful EVIL creature?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

#### The summoned monster's alignment subtype affects the spell's descriptor

The spell [*summon monster I*](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/s/summon-monster) (*et al.*) says, "When you use a summoning spell to summon a creature with an alignment or elemental subtype, it [the summoning spell] is a spell of that type." Hence, for example, a [lemure](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/monster-listings/outsiders/devil/lemure/summoned-creature-lemure)'s alignment subtype is [evil](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/rules-for-monsters/creature-types#subtype-evil) (and, technically, [lawful](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/rules-for-monsters/creature-types#subtype-lawful)), so when *summon monster II* would be used to summon a lemure, that *summon monster II* spell would gain the evil (and lawful) [descriptor](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic#TOC-Descriptor-), and the spell couldn't be cast to summon a lemure by a good (or chaotic) [cleric](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/cleric).

Comment: @Fering I think there's some jumbling of technical terms in this question. A creature's alignment can be different from its alignment subtype, a spell's school is different from its descriptor, and a spell's description is also different from a spell's descriptor. I think my answer cuts through all of that, but let me know if you need more.

Comment: I had been looking for this paragraph and somehow missed it. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: @Fering You're welcome. (Note that I dislike the idea of these Schrödinger spells that you don't really *know* their descriptors until they're cast. I kind of wish there were 4 different *summon monster* spell lines (*summon good monster*, *summon lawful monster*, and so on) just to avoid that weirdness.)

Comment: Also this: Chaotic, Evil, Good, and Lawful Spells A cleric can't cast spells of an alignment opposed to her own or her deity's (if she has one).